# What do we need from them to use their Azure Active Directory.

Tags: azure-active-directory

Currently we are developing an application in Angular to be hosted in Azure cloud. I need to  tell the customer what do we need from them to use their Azure Active Directory.  Could someone help me with this question asked by my manager?

Answer (score 0):

these fields is required

```
<add key="ClientId" value="Enter_the_Application_Id_here" />
<add key="RedirectUrl" value="Enter_the_Redirect_Url_here" />
<add key="Tenant" value="common" />
<add key="Authority" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}" />
```

for more information pl read this artical
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/GuidedSetups/active-directory-aspnetwebapp-v1